# how to implement AAShareBubles

Tags: ios, swift

I want to share my image on Facebook, Twitter when I click share button on navigation bar. I use this library to implement that sharing https://github.com/mixdesign/AAShareBubbles. But my code doesn't work, I click on that share button in navigation bar but it only print, doesn't show any facebook, twitter share button.

May anyone help me with this.

My code:

```
@IBAction func onShareTouched(sender: AnyObject) {

//    print("share")
//
//    let myShare = "I am feeling *** today"
//
//    let shareVC: UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [myShare], applicationActivities: nil)
//    self.presentViewController(shareVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    print("share bubles")
//    let shareBubles: AAShareBubbles = AAShareBubbles.init(point: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100), radius: 100, inView: self.view)
    let shareBubles: AAShareBubbles = AAShareBubbles.init(centeredInWindowWithRadius: 100)
    shareBubles.delegate = self
    shareBubles.bubbleRadius = 45
    shareBubles.showFacebookBubble = true
    shareBubles.showTwitterBubble = true
    shareBubles.showGooglePlusBubble = true
    shareBubles.showMailBubble = true
    shareBubles.showTumblrBubble = true
    shareBubles.showVkBubble = true
    shareBubles.addCustomButtonWithIcon(UIImage(named: "loveface"), backgroundColor: UIColor.greenColor(), andButtonId: 100)

  }
```

Comment: shareBubles.show(); ??

Comment: Thank a lot, just forgot this line :D. It work now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you missed

```
shareBubles.show();
```